# CanvasJS Chart Data not showing

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

Got a question for you. I'm working with CanvasJS charts, and the chart is not showing data when rendering.

First i'm initialising the chart using this:

```
integrity.initChart = function() {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("integrityChart", {
        animationEnabled: true,
        animationDuration: 2000,
        title: {
            text: integrity.stockCode + " Integrity"
        },
        axisX: {
            title: "Date"
        },
        axisY: {
            title: "Value"
        },
        toolTip: {
            shared: true
        },
        legend: {
            cursor: "pointer",
            verticalAlign: "top",
            horizontalAlign: "center",
            dockInsidePlotArea: true,
            itemclick: toogleDataSeries
        },
        data: [
        {
            toolTipContent: "{x} - {y} (Stoploss: {stoploss}%)",
            type:"line",
            name: "Integrity minute",
            yValueFormatString: "###.##",
            showInLegend: true,
            markerSize: 0,
            dataPoints: [

            ]
        },
        {
            toolTipContent: "{x} - {y} (Stoploss: {stoploss}%)",
            type: "line",
            name: "Integrity hour",
            showInLegend: true,
            yValueFormatString: "###.##",
            markerSize: 0,
            dataPoints: [

            ]
        },
        {
            toolTipContent: "{x} - {y} (Stoploss: {stoploss}%)",
            type: "line",
            name: "Integrity day",
            showInLegend: true,
            yValueFormatString: "###.##",
            markerSize: 0,
            dataPoints: [

            ]
        }
    ]
    });

    integrity.chartObject = chart;
}
```

And i can see the chart, very nicely, but then i call the update data method.

```
integrity.renderChart = function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: integrity.requestBase + '&data=integrity',
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success:function(result) {
          var lowest = null;
          var highest = null;
          var i = 0;

            for (var key in result) {
                if (result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    i = 0;
                    while (i < result[key].length) {
                        if (lowest == null) {
                            lowest = result[key][i].y;
                            highest = result[key][i].y;
                        }

                        if (lowest > result[key][i].y) {
                            lowest = result[key][i].y;
                        }

                        if (highest < result[key][i].y) {
                            highest = result[key][i].y;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }

          integrity.chartObject.options.axisY.viewportMinimum = lowest-(highest-lowest);
          integrity.chartObject.options.axisY.viewportMaximum = highest+(highest-lowest);
          integrity.chartObject.options.axisY.margin = 0;
          integrity.chartObject.options.data[0].dataPoints = result.minute;
          integrity.chartObject.options.data[1].dataPoints = result.hour;
          integrity.chartObject.options.data[2].dataPoints = result.day;
          integrity.chartObject.render();
      }
  });
}
```

And still no data is to be found, i did an alert(result.day.length) and it did show me ca 70 entries, so the data is getting set to the dataPoints well, but no joy.

Here's a sample of the data as well.

```js
{
  "day": [
    {
      "x": "2018-05-30 12:23:19",
      "y": 81.29,
      "stoploss": 10
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-30 12:30:18",
      "y": 84.51,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-30 12:37:11",
      "y": 85.2,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-30 12:44:24",
      "y": 85.41,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 00:27:03",
      "y": -144.35,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 00:34:51",
      "y": -194.17,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 09:37:28",
      "y": 3.8,
      "stoploss": 10
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 09:45:56",
      "y": 3.8,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 09:54:41",
      "y": -140.64,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 10:03:01",
      "y": -182.18,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 10:48:14",
      "y": 85.82,
      "stoploss": 10
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 10:56:57",
      "y": 90.2,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 11:05:10",
      "y": 76.49,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 11:13:34",
      "y": 74.83,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 11:55:51",
      "y": 138.49,
      "stoploss": 10
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 12:05:04",
      "y": 134.73,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 12:14:32",
      "y": 138.75,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 12:23:51",
      "y": 137.17,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-03 16:24:35",
      "y": 127.25,
      "stoploss": 10
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-03 16:28:44",
      "y": 128.78,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-03 16:32:42",
      "y": 132.29,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-03 16:36:42",
      "y": 131.9,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 19:52:15",
      "y": 110.21,
      "stoploss": 10
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 20:00:58",
      "y": 46.24,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 20:09:46",
      "y": 118.59,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 20:18:59",
      "y": 118.59,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-06 00:13:35",
      "y": -66.23,
      "stoploss": 10
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-06 00:22:41",
      "y": -66.23,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-06 00:31:41",
      "y": -66.23,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-06 00:40:45",
      "y": -161.35,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-07 00:13:25",
      "y": -58.91,
      "stoploss": 10
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-07 00:23:31",
      "y": -58.91,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-07 00:32:33",
      "y": -58.91,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-07 00:41:44",
      "y": -157.95,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-08 00:13:15",
      "y": 25.88,
      "stoploss": 10
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-08 00:22:37",
      "y": 25.88,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-08 00:31:52",
      "y": 25.88,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-08 00:40:49",
      "y": -77.03,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 11:54:21",
      "y": 105.89,
      "stoploss": 10
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 12:05:49",
      "y": 147.62,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 12:16:58",
      "y": 128.44,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 12:28:06",
      "y": 154,
      "stoploss": 3
    }
  ],
  "minute": [
    {
      "x": "2018-05-30 12:34:49",
      "y": 35.63,
      "stoploss": 4
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-30 12:53:40",
      "y": 46.9,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-30 13:11:51",
      "y": 19.02,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-30 13:30:26",
      "y": 37.48,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-30 13:47:58",
      "y": 45.86,
      "stoploss": 0.75
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-30 14:06:07",
      "y": 31.35,
      "stoploss": 0.5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 00:19:51",
      "y": 7.28,
      "stoploss": 4
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 00:33:33",
      "y": 12.43,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 00:45:28",
      "y": 11.59,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 00:56:05",
      "y": 2.81,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 01:05:56",
      "y": 10.61,
      "stoploss": 0.75
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 01:15:07",
      "y": 3.71,
      "stoploss": 0.5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 09:48:04",
      "y": 16.35,
      "stoploss": 4
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 10:09:00",
      "y": 31.83,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 10:59:25",
      "y": 45.54,
      "stoploss": 4
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 12:16:57",
      "y": 55.82,
      "stoploss": 4
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-01 00:13:12",
      "y": 6.67,
      "stoploss": 4
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-01 00:21:56",
      "y": 5.64,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-01 00:30:07",
      "y": 12.99,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-01 00:37:36",
      "y": 10.41,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-01 00:44:41",
      "y": 3.77,
      "stoploss": 0.75
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-01 00:51:39",
      "y": 0.43,
      "stoploss": 0.5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-02 00:13:14",
      "y": 7.28,
      "stoploss": 4
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-02 00:21:54",
      "y": 6.9,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-02 00:30:04",
      "y": 9.48,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-02 00:37:36",
      "y": 7.03,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-02 00:44:34",
      "y": 12.76,
      "stoploss": 0.75
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-02 00:51:24",
      "y": 5.47,
      "stoploss": 0.5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 00:19:41",
      "y": 1.67,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 00:26:59",
      "y": 0.95,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 00:33:49",
      "y": 0.73,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 00:46:26",
      "y": 0.73,
      "stoploss": 0.5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 20:19:43",
      "y": 42.77,
      "stoploss": 4
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 20:50:24",
      "y": 33.35,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 21:19:03",
      "y": 32.95,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 21:46:06",
      "y": 20.87,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 22:10:59",
      "y": 11.25,
      "stoploss": 0.75
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 22:34:21",
      "y": 14.94,
      "stoploss": 0.5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-06 00:21:35",
      "y": 5,
      "stoploss": 4
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-06 00:37:56",
      "y": 3.09,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-06 00:52:35",
      "y": 7.56,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-06 01:06:55",
      "y": 7.56,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-06 01:20:28",
      "y": 1.41,
      "stoploss": 0.75
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-06 01:33:35",
      "y": 1.71,
      "stoploss": 0.5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-07 00:21:33",
      "y": 10.97,
      "stoploss": 4
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-07 00:38:31",
      "y": 7.47,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-07 00:54:43",
      "y": 4.89,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-08 00:24:25",
      "y": 18.93,
      "stoploss": 4
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-08 00:43:49",
      "y": 5.91,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-08 01:02:08",
      "y": 3.74,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-08 01:18:32",
      "y": 6.93,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-08 01:33:46",
      "y": 9.44,
      "stoploss": 0.75
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-09 00:24:03",
      "y": 2.2,
      "stoploss": 4
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-09 00:42:15",
      "y": 0.32,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-09 00:58:49",
      "y": 3.26,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-09 01:30:28",
      "y": 0.7,
      "stoploss": 0.75
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 00:21:39",
      "y": 4.45,
      "stoploss": 4
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 00:37:55",
      "y": 2.97,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 00:54:02",
      "y": 9.16,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 01:09:04",
      "y": 0.25,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 01:23:56",
      "y": 1.43,
      "stoploss": 0.75
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 01:36:53",
      "y": 4.38,
      "stoploss": 0.5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 12:23:45",
      "y": 39.36,
      "stoploss": 4
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 13:00:28",
      "y": 33.25,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 13:37:14",
      "y": 46.48,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-13 00:20:59",
      "y": 12.01,
      "stoploss": 4
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-13 00:40:09",
      "y": 0.75,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-13 00:57:54",
      "y": 0.55,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-13 01:12:55",
      "y": 0.5,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-13 01:27:47",
      "y": 3,
      "stoploss": 0.75
    }
  ],
  "hour": [
    {
      "x": "2018-05-30 12:35:12",
      "y": -71.36,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-30 12:54:16",
      "y": -96.86,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-30 13:13:00",
      "y": -110.86,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-30 13:33:11",
      "y": -79.86,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-30 13:52:32",
      "y": -134.34,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 00:37:12",
      "y": 70.52,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 01:11:47",
      "y": 80.79,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 01:45:49",
      "y": 78.55,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 02:19:58",
      "y": 79.35,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 02:54:19",
      "y": 120.08,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 10:03:50",
      "y": 2.6,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 11:10:52",
      "y": 130.15,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-05-31 12:20:51",
      "y": 113.96,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-01 00:33:30",
      "y": 232.75,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-01 01:04:04",
      "y": 204.37,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-01 01:34:53",
      "y": 233.88,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-01 02:06:41",
      "y": 225.59,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-01 02:37:02",
      "y": 209.71,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-02 00:33:35",
      "y": 214.83,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-02 01:03:41",
      "y": 200.75,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-02 01:33:20",
      "y": 214.83,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-02 02:04:22",
      "y": 200.75,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-02 02:35:17",
      "y": 199.88,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-03 00:33:55",
      "y": 214.83,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-03 01:04:20",
      "y": 200.75,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-03 01:35:12",
      "y": 208.15,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-03 02:06:41",
      "y": 214.16,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-03 02:37:48",
      "y": 187.27,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-04 00:33:52",
      "y": 214.83,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-04 01:04:27",
      "y": 200.75,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-04 01:35:14",
      "y": 208.15,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-04 02:05:50",
      "y": 214.16,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-04 02:36:16",
      "y": 194.82,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 00:34:25",
      "y": 105.78,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 01:05:44",
      "y": 144.34,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 01:37:42",
      "y": 111.79,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 02:09:23",
      "y": 132.81,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 02:41:08",
      "y": 92.17,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 20:24:13",
      "y": 207.02,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 21:00:57",
      "y": 189.36,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 21:36:34",
      "y": 202.61,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 22:12:57",
      "y": 174.41,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-05 22:49:35",
      "y": 171.98,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-06 00:39:39",
      "y": 178.5,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-06 01:15:28",
      "y": 148.71,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-06 01:51:41",
      "y": 184.62,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-06 02:27:17",
      "y": 160.87,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-06 03:02:59",
      "y": 187.7,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-07 00:40:59",
      "y": 192.14,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-07 01:17:25",
      "y": 194.25,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-07 01:53:54",
      "y": 194.11,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-07 02:30:58",
      "y": 165.61,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-07 03:07:24",
      "y": 195.16,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-08 00:41:27",
      "y": 89.22,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-08 01:18:40",
      "y": 37.08,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-08 01:56:18",
      "y": 47.82,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-08 02:33:26",
      "y": 25.93,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-08 03:10:03",
      "y": 16.87,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-09 00:32:37",
      "y": 108.62,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-09 01:00:59",
      "y": 84.9,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-09 01:28:42",
      "y": 54.64,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-09 01:56:52",
      "y": 95,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-09 02:25:51",
      "y": 84.19,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 00:31:31",
      "y": 90.56,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 00:58:57",
      "y": 66.41,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 01:26:19",
      "y": 47.07,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 01:52:17",
      "y": 79.47,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 02:18:44",
      "y": 21.59,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 12:12:09",
      "y": 40.95,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 12:39:36",
      "y": 62.88,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 13:07:54",
      "y": 35.63,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 13:36:09",
      "y": 113.16,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-12 14:04:27",
      "y": 49.53,
      "stoploss": 1
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-13 00:29:40",
      "y": 106.13,
      "stoploss": 7
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-13 00:55:23",
      "y": 63.13,
      "stoploss": 5
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-13 01:21:11",
      "y": 32.94,
      "stoploss": 3
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-13 01:46:40",
      "y": 84.03,
      "stoploss": 2
    },
    {
      "x": "2018-06-13 02:13:10",
      "y": 24.88,
      "stoploss": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

X axis takes dateobject as input, not just date as a string.